# Can I register two different listeners for same sensor in parallel?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I would like to register two different listeners for the Accelerator service with different rates.

Like so:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(mCoarseListener, mAccelerometer, COARSE_RATE_MICROS, mListenerHandler);
mSensorManager.registerListener(mFineListener, mAccelerometer, FINE_RATE_MICROS, mListenerHandler);
```

I know I could just use one and differentiate within the listener but this way it would be much cleaner.

Comment: Did you try? If yes, did you get an error? What is your question !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to register two different listeners for the Accelerator service

An activity that listens to sensor events is not acquiring a resource lock on a sensor; the `SensorManager` always owns the sensors.

Given that, there is no reason multiple listeners could not receive sensor broadcasts at the same time (your activity, another activity, Android OS services that are running in the background and telling the user how many steps they have taken at the end of the month).

The case you bring up is just one example of multiple listeners listening to a sensor, and it should not matter at all that both listeners are in the same activity.